# When a conditional probability becomes a mapping to probability measures

Tags: probability-theory

In [the Wikipedia article for conditional expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation),  conditional probability is defined in terms of conditional expectation.

1. Given a sub sigma algebra of the one
   on a probability space.

   Given a probability space $(\Omega,
   \mathcal{F}, P)$, a conditional
   probability $P(A \mid \mathcal{B})$
   of a measurable subset $A \in
   \mathcal{F}$ given a sub sigma
   algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of
   $\mathcal{F}$, is defined as the
   conditional expectation $E(A \mid
   \mathcal{B})$ of indicator function
   $1_A$ of $A$ given $\mathcal{B}$,
   i.e. $$ P(A \mid \mathcal{B}): = E(1_A
   \mid \mathcal{B}), \forall A \in
   \mathcal{F}.$$

   So actually the conditional
   probability $P(\cdot \mid
   \mathcal{B})$ is a mapping $: \Omega
   \times \mathcal{F} \rightarrow
   \mathbb{R}$.

   A conditional probability $P(\cdot
   \mid \mathcal{B})$ is called regular if
   $P(\cdot|\mathcal{B})(\omega),
   \forall \omega \in \Omega$ is also a
   probability measure.

   **Question:**

   What are some
   necessary and/or sufficient
   conditions for a conditional
   probability $P(\cdot \mid
   \mathcal{B})$ to be regular?
2. Given a random variable on a probability space.

   Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$
   is a probability space and $(U,
   \mathcal{\Sigma})$ is a measurable
   space. There seem to be two ways of
   defining the conditional expectation
   $E(X\mid Y)$ of a r.v. $X: \Omega
   \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given
   another r.v. $Y: \Omega \rightarrow
   U$, either as a
   $\sigma(Y)$-measurable mapping $:
   \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, or
   as a $\Sigma$-measurable mapping $:
   U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,  as [in
   my previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23620/definition-of-conditional-expectation-of-a-random-variable-given-another-one).

   If one let $X$ to be the indicator
   function $1_A$ for some $A \in
   \mathcal{F}$, one can similarly
   define  $E(1_A \mid Y)$ to be
   conditional probability of $A$ given
   $Y$, denoted as $P(A\mid Y)$.
   Therefore $P(\cdot \mid Y)$ is a
   mapping $: \Omega \times \mathcal{F}
   \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or a mapping
   $: U \times \mathcal{F} \rightarrow
   \mathbb{R}$.

   **Questions:**

   (1). What are some necessary and/or
   sufficient conditions for $P(\cdot
       \mid Y)$ to be regular, i.e. to be a
   mapping $: \Omega \rightarrow \{
       \text{probability measures on
       }(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \}$ or a
   mapping $: U \rightarrow \{
       \text{probability measures on
       }(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \}$?

   (2). Under what kinds of conditions, will
   $P(X \mid Y)$ defined as above be
   equal to the ratio $\frac{P(X, Y)}{P(Y)}$, the
   definition used in elementary
   probability?

Thanks and regards! References (links or books) will also be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1, I don't know if necessary and sufficient conditions exist but here are two sufficient conditions I know :

- the space is a standard probability space, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space),
- the space is a Radon space, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_space).

I think that there  is another one but I can't remember its exact form, except that I know that the space should be Polish and the sigma-algebra countably generated, and maybe another condition.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! Some other references on this topic?

Answer (score 9):

Conditional probabilities do not give a unique function on the sample space. Since conditional expectations are only defined up to a measure zero set and one has to make an uncountable number of selections, the essential problem is whether one can "glue" them together in coherent way, so that you can actually calculate conditional probabilities by integrating the function. There are several notions of regular conditional probabilities and [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-13/issue-1/The-Existence-of-Regular-Conditional-Probabilities--Necessary-and-Sufficient/10.1214/aop/1176993081.full) paper by Faden gives necessary and sufficient conditions for some of them. For the particular version you mentioned, little is known about necessary conditions. The strongest results on the existence of regular conditional probabilities can be found in [this](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11771) paper by Pachl, but he only requires them to be measurable with respect to the completion of the measure. The machinery he uses is rather sophisticated, his method is based on using a [lifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_theory) that he then shows (under some condition, compactness) to give a countably additive probability.
The most extensive resource on conditional probabilities is probably the book [Conditional Measures and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1574445936) by M.M. Rao. The book is not recommended for its readability. Your question is addressed in chapter 3 in a comprehensive manner.